# Parent process not running

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to write a simple SMS server in `c` and have a function that generates 2 processes(one for listening and another for writing), but the parent process doesn't seem to be running (the debug messages are not being printed) despite the fork call not generating an error...

```
void connection (int sock, char username[], int *rear, int *front, msg queue_array[])
{
    int n, pid;
    char buffer[256], dest[64]; 
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) error("ERROR on fork call");
    while(1)
    {
        if(pid > 0)
        {
            bzero(buffer,256);
            n = read(sock,buffer,255);

            if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

            printf("Here is the full message: %s\n",buffer);

            //n = write(sock,"I got your message!\n",18);
            //if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
            //interpret(buffer, username);

            //TEMPORARY!!!!!    

            msg *temp;
            temp = (msg *)(malloc(sizeof(msg)));
            strcpy(temp->dest, "destiny");
            strcpy(temp->text, "blahblah");
            insert(temp, rear, front, queue_array); //Por a mensagem na queue

        }
        else
        {
            sleep(1); 
            /*Verificar se a file está vazia*/
            printf("hi?");
            printf("yooooo: %d", *front);
            if(*front != -1) 
            {
                /*verificar se a primeira mensagem da queue é destinada a esta pessoa*/
                strcpy(dest, queue_array[*front].dest); 
                printf("%s != destiny", dest);
                if(strcmp(dest, "destiny") == 0)
                {
                    printf("passou o teste\n");
                    strcpy(buffer, queue_array[*front].text);
                    delete(rear, front);
                    n = write(sock,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Try using `stderr`, since you don't seem to like using newlines.

Comment: To clarify what `jxh` is saying: `stdout` is generally line buffered, so you need to add `\n` at the end of your `printf`s to make the output visible immediately. Or print to the unbuffered `stderr`.